# The output is 100 but i don't understand why

Tags: python, function, recursion

The output is 100 but i don't understand why. Can someone give some insight into how this code works step by step.

```
def fun(n):
    if (n > 100):
        return n - 5
    return fun(fun(n+11))
print(fun(45))
```

Comment: add print(n) after def fun. I think, you will aunderstand

Comment: Grab a sheet of paper and write out the tree of recursive calls.  It should probably fit on one sheet, and you will see exactly why you get this output.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose your code.

```py
def fun(n): 
    if (n > 100): 
        return n - 5 
    return fun(fun(n+11)) 
print(fun(45))
```

```sh
> n =45, n > 100 == False, return fun(fun(n + 11))
    > fun(45+11) == fun(56), n = 56, 56 > 11 == False, return fun(fun(n + 11))
        > fun(56+11), n = 67
           > fun(67+11), n = 78
               > fun(78+11), n = 89
                   > fun(89 + 11), n= 100
                       > fun(100+11), n = 111
                       > fun(111), n > 100 return 111 - 5
                   > fun(106), return 106 - 5
               > fun(101), return 101 - 5
           > fun(96), return fun(fun(96+11))
               > fun(107), return 107 - 5
               > fun(102), return 102 - 5
           > fun(97), return fun(fun(97+11))
               > 108 - 5
               > 103 - 5
            > fun(98)
                > 109 - 5
                > 104 - 5
             > fun(99)
                > 110 - 5
       > 105 - 5, return 100
```

And here with code:

```py
def fun(n, s):
    space = " " * s
    if (n > 100):
        print(f"{space} > return {n}-5={n-5}")
        return [n - 5, s - 3]
    print(f"{space} > return fun(fun({n} + 11))\n {space + '   '} > return fun(fun({n+11}))")
    return fun(*fun(n+11, s+3))

print(fun(45, 0))
```

Comment: Do you write this manually or there is something soft to do listings like this?

Comment: Not I know, unfortunately it was by hand, just for killing time.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed in some comments, your best chance is to write down what is going on on paper:

- When `n` is lower than 100, you add 11 to `n`, and go deeper.
- When `n` is higher than 100, you return `n-5`, and go higher.

If you want to represent this on paper, you can go down each time you add 11, and return up each time you subtract 5. You'll have your result when surpass your starting point, going up.

```
START                                                100
 |                                                    ^
 V                                                    |
```

---

```
 45                                        99    99  105
 56                            98    98   104   110  110
 67                 97    97  103   109   109
 78     96    96   102   108  108
 89    101   107   107
 100   106
 111   111
```

Since you're experimenting with double recursion, I suppose you're already familiar with recursion; if not, have a look [there](https://thepythonguru.com/python-recursive-functions/) first!